# Adapt this google docs autofill script to make a Google Presentation rather than a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides

I'm new to Google Scripts (but not programming generally).

I'm trying to use a google spreadsheet to make a bunch of google presentation docs, one per row in the source spreadsheet.

I'm following this, which has some nice, clean code for making google docs.
https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/

I like the way it works generally, where it only makes the doc if the 'Document Link' column in the source data sheet isn't populated.

It works for me, and i can use it to make a bunch of google docs with my dynamic vars filled in from the sheet - so far so good.  However, I can't work out how to adapt it to make slideshows instead.

My source data is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXLNd6vdavC0VXVA4egGydRKN-7Toga2m9RGm2btz3M/edit#gid=0

And my Presentation template is here: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/127JIyUlFsfz2ST7lQz8iPOzTPwYqh6yIQ1oj-FQPdOY/edit#slide=id.p

And my Document template is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dxtrCAf7m7SLf7mG6ShCbVIJCQXmjaca4r1VnNWh1Kk/edit

So, this script works with the Document template: it makes a new Google Document for each row in the spreadsheet, filling in the variables.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  //CHANGED TO THE ID OF MY PRESENTATION TEMPLATE
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1dxtrCAf7m7SLf7mG6ShCbVIJCQXmjaca4r1VnNWh1Kk');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1PJEPE38E9ZryW12ijASk3NgebxqMzRim')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[5]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Position}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Hire Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Hourly Wage}}', row[4]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

I tried just using the presentation ID in place of the sample document ID, in the line where we tell it the id of the template:

```
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1dxtrCAf7m7SLf7mG6ShCbVIJCQXmjaca4r1VnNWh1Kk');
```

but i get this error:

```
Exception: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
  const googleDocTemplate = SlidesApp.openById('1dxtrCAf7m7SLf7mG6ShCbVIJCQXmjaca4r1VnNWh1Kk');
```

But then I get

```
TypeError: googleDocTemplate.makeCopy is not a function
```

so i guess the Presentation's ewquivalent function to makeCopy is called something else - or it doesn't have one?

Can someone help? I'm hoping it just needs a couple of tweaks... thanks

Comment: When I saw your Google Slide, only `Hello {{First Name}}` and `You are a {{Position}}` are put on the 1st slide. But, in your script, other placeholders are used. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script or your Google Slide. How about this? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike They are just left over from the sample doc used in that tutorial.  The script still works even if they aren't referenced (when making a google doc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not copy a Presentation but you can copy the file.  Then open the copy and replace the text.  I let you figure out the destination.

```
function createNewGooglePresentation() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Data");
    let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    rows.shift(); // remove the headers
    let template = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    let urls = [];
    rows.forEach( row => {
        if( row[5] === "" ) {
          let file = template.makeCopy( row[1]+", "+row[0]+" Employee Details" );
          let presentation = SlidesApp.openById(file.getId());
          urls.push([file.getUrl()])
          let slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];  // there is only one slide
          slide.replaceAllText("{{First Name}}",row[0]);
          slide.replaceAllText("{{Position}}",row[2]);
          presentation.saveAndClose();
        }
        else {
          urls.push([row[5]]);
        }
      }
    );
    sheet.getRange(2,6,urls.length,1).setValues(urls);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in createNewGooglePresentation: "+err)
  }
}
```

References

- [File.makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String))
- [Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides())
- [Slide.replaceAllText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#replaceAllText(String,String))

Comment: Thanks - i'm getting this error: `Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.` - is it trying to open the source data spreadsheet while still on the script editing page maybe?

Comment: Ah, i needed to just save the script changes, not run them (running them did work with my initial google docs version).  It's working now, thanks!